# Скрытие элементов списка

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать такую возможность:
Чтобы когда нажималась кнопка Войти в комнату, уже открытая комната закрывалась?
Либо когда нажималась кнопка Войти в комнату, весь список скрывался, кроме выбранной комнаты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Постарался в комментариях кода объяснить каким образом можно реализовать передачу свойств между компонентами. Это как один из вариантов.

```js
Vue.component('rooms-list', {
  template: `<div>
      <h1 v-if="currentRoom">Вы в комнате № {{ currentRoom }}</h1>
      <h1 v-else>Выберите комнату</h1>
      <template v-for="room in rooms">
        <room-row
          v-bind="room"
          :current.sync="currentRoom"
          @update-room="onUpdateRoom" />
      </template>
    </div>`,
  /**
   * Эти свойства были переданы в этот компонент как v-bind="rooms".
   */
  props: {
    // Список всех комнат.
    list: Array,
    // Поле с номером текущей комнаты.
    current: Number
  },
  data() {
    return {
      // Для работы с переданными свойствами задаём им локальный статус.
      rooms: this.$props.list,
      currentRoom: this.$props.current,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    /**
     * Обновляем данные о комнатах.
     * Данный метод вызывается из дочернего путем
     * this.$emit('update-room', {...})
     */
    onUpdateRoom(room) {
      // Ищем индекс переданной `room` комнаты в списке.
      const roomIndex = this.rooms
        .findIndex(item => item.id === room.id)

      // Обновляем информацию о комнатах.
      this.rooms.splice(roomIndex, 1, room)
    }
  },
})

Vue.component('room-row', {
  template: `<div>
      <div v-if="isActiveRoom">
        <button type="button" @click="cameOut">Выйти из комнаты №{{ id }}</button><br/>
        <label><input type="checkbox" v-model="active" /> Лампочка {{ active | humanValue }}</label>
      </div>
      <div v-else-if="nonSelectedRoom">
        <button type="button" @click="comeIn">Войти в комнату №{{ id }}</button>
      </div>
    </div>`,
  props: {
    id: Number,
    activeLamp: Boolean,
    // Поле с номером текущей комнаты, переданный с модификатором `.sync`
    // Модификатор обеспечит двустороннюю привязку.
    // При изменении его в одном из компонентов, остальные компоненты,
    // через родительский будут об этом знать незамедлительно.
    current: Number,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      // Определяем модель для состояния лампочки.
      active: this.$props.activeLamp
    }
  },
  computed: {
    /**
     * Мы находимся в этой комнате.
     * Отобразим лампочку и создадим возможность выйти из комнаты.
     */
    isActiveRoom() {
      return this.current === this.id
    },
    /**
     * Мы не в одной из комнат.
     * Отобразим весь список комнат.
     */
    nonSelectedRoom() {
      return !this.current
    }
  },
  filters: {
    humanValue(value) {
      return !!value ? 'включена' : 'выключена'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    /**
     * Заходим в комнату.
     */
    comeIn() {
      // Оповещаем родительский компонент о том,
      // что необходимо обновить данные о номере текущей комнаты.
      this.$emit('update:current', this.id)
    },
    /**
     * Выходим из комнаты.
     */
    cameOut() {
      // Хлопаем дверью.
      this.$emit('update:current', 0)
      // Обновляем данные о текущей комнате в родительском компоненте.
      // Родительский элемент в свою очередь вызовет метод,
      // записанный как `@update-room="onUpdateRoom"`
      this.$emit('update-room', {
        id: this.id,
        activeLamp: this.active
      })
    },
  }
})

const APP = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    // Наша модель. Так сказать общага )
    rooms: {
      // Поле с номером текущей комнаты.
      // По умолчанию мы никуда еще не вошли.
      current: 0,
      // Список всех комнат.
      // Первое поле - это номер.
      // Второе - отображает состояние выключателя
      list: [{
          id: 1,
          activeLamp: false
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          activeLamp: false
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          activeLamp: false
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          activeLamp: false
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          activeLamp: false
        },
      ]
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <!--
    Передаём данные о комнатах - v-bind="rooms" как объект.
    Эти данные определены при инициализации App в поле `data: {...}`.
    Эта запись равнозначна записи
      :current="rooms.current" :list="rooms.list"
    НО: изменение объекта или массива внутри дочернего компонента
    будет влиять на состояние родителя.
  -->
  <rooms-list v-bind="rooms"></rooms-list>
  <pre>{{ rooms }}</pre>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
```

Comment: Хороший пример на обмен событиями между компонентами. Я бы даже сказал, что как только ТС освоит более простые примеры - лучше ему как раз разобрать ваш пример.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша проблема в том, что вы описываете лампочку только одной переменной - id, при этом никак не озвучивая, что ещё у лампы есть состояние. Как только вы введёте состояние в виде [реактивной переменной](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) ваша жизнь многократно упростится:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div>лампа # {{ this.lamp.id }}, состояние: {{ lamp.light ? 'включена' : 'выключена' }}</div>
    <div>
      <button v-on:click="changeState">CLICKME</button>
    </div>
    <div v-if="lamp.light">ещё какой-то блок для включенной лампы</div>
    <div v-else>ещё какой-то блок для выключенной лампы</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Lamp",
  props: {
    lamp: {
      id: 0,
      light: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    changeState: function() {
      this.lamp.light = !this.lamp.light;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Теперь в списке ламп можно указывать их начальное состояние:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello lampls</h1>
    <lamp v-for="item in lamps" :key="item.id" :lamp="item"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Lamp from "@/components/Lamp";

export default {
  name: "Lamps",
  components: { Lamp },
  data() {
    return {
      lamps: [{ id: 1, light: false }, { id: 2, light: true }]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

Проверяем работу:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Hello lampls</h1>
    <lamps></lamps>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Lamps from "@/components/Lamps";

export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  components: { Lamps }
};
</script>
```

Всё выводится, всё кликается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В остальном ваша логика не очень понятна. "Вошёл в комнату - комната закрылась", это пожалуй так же нелогично как и "включил лампу - потекла вода из крана". В общем, оставляю вам описание условий что и от чего должно зависеть на самостоятельную проработку.

Я пытался понять логику, у меня получалось, что вам нужно описывать состояние на уровне комнаты, но дальше начались сплошные предположения и я решил, что это вам лучше самому разобрать.

Вероятнее всего (но это чисто мои предположения), вы хотели логику "только одна из комнат может быть в состоянии Open. При нажатии на кнопку войти в комнату все остальные должны закрываться". Если так, то вам на уровне блока rooms нужна одна реактивная переменная selected_room_id и отрисовка room в зависимости от значения этой переменной (в самом простом случае можно обойтись только навешиванием/скрыванием css класса selected и описанием css правил типа display:none)

И вот ещё. Вы сейчас думаете об этой функциональности, как о размещённой на одной странице, но вполне возможно, что стоило бы рассмотреть это как два разных url: на одной есть список всех комнат и напротив каждой комнаты ссылка на переход к странице управления выбранной комнатой, где отображать название комнаты, списки её лампочек и т.п. В этом случае скрытие всех других комнат у вас будет "из коробки".

Подумайте, возможно у вас сформулируется на основании этого новый вопрос с новыми правилами что и как переключать.