# При разбивке проекта на компоненты сыплются ошибки в консоли

Tags: vue.js

Решила попробовать уже написанный проект разбить на компоненты Vue и столкнулась с проблемой, что у меня перестали по итогу работать практически все функции, т.к. компоненты сейчас толком не связаны.

Браузер выдает следующие ошибки:

1) При заполнении форм, а также при клике в таблице на кнопку с ярлычком в виде карандаша:

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "productName"

2) При отправке данных формы кнопка "Добавить" также не работает. Ошибки:

> Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

---

Код исходного приложения (до разбиения на компоненты):

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#productList',
  data: {
    productName: '',
    quantity: 1,
    cost: 1,
    isTouched: false,
    currentItemIndex: null,
    products: [{
        product: 'Хлеб',
        quantity: 4,
        cost: 30
      }, {
        product: 'Яблоко',
        quantity: 8,
        cost: 18
      }]
  },

  computed: {
    inputValidation: function() {
      return this.productName.trim().length == 0 ||
        this.quantity <= 0 ||
        this.cost <= 0
    }
  },
  
  methods: {
    applyDefaultValues: function() {
      this.productName = '';
      this.quantity = 1;
      this.cost = 1;
      this.currentItemIndex = null;
    },

    choiceAction: function() {
      this.currentItemIndex == null ? this.addItem() : this.saveChanges();
    },

    addItem: function() {
      var newValue = {
        product: this.productName,
        quantity: this.quantity,
        cost: this.cost
      };
      this.products.push(newValue)
      this.applyDefaultValues()
      this.isTouched = false;
    },

    edit: function(index) {
      var editingItem = this.products[index];

      this.productName = editingItem.product;
      this.quantity = editingItem.quantity;
      this.cost = editingItem.cost;

      this.currentItemIndex = index;
    },

    saveChanges: function() {
      var newObject = {
        product: this.productName,
        quantity: this.quantity,
        cost: this.cost
      }
      this.products.splice(this.currentItemIndex, 1, newObject);
      this.applyDefaultValues()
      this.isTouched = false;
    },

    deleteItem: function(index) {
      this.products.splice(index, 1);
    },

    blurCondition: function() {
      this.isTouched = true;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(255, 246, 246);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #eaeafe8c, #e3e3e3);
}

.productProject {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}

.productProject__forms {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.productProject__forms__errorMessage {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #ff0000;
  width: 190px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.productProject__forms__buttons {
  display: flex;
}

.productProject__forms span {
  display: block;
  width: 90px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.productProject__productList--btnStyle {
  width: 124px;
}

.productProject__productList__icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.productProject__productList__icons__deleteIcon {
  background: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/61/61848.png) no-repeat;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-size: contain;
  opacity: .2;
}

.productProject__productList__icons__deleteIcon:hover,
.productProject__productList__icons__editIcon:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.productProject__productList__icons__editIcon {
  background: url(https://img2.freepng.ru/20180616/fiu/kisspng-computer-icons-drawing-pencil-pencil-icon-5b256b0984a045.2039086015291788895433.jpg) no-repeat;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-size: contain;
  opacity: .2;
}

.productProject button {
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #A1887F, #795548);
  border: 2px solid #795548;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #2D2020;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.productProject button:disabled {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #c1c1c2, #6e6e6e);
  border: 2px solid #979797;
}

.productProject button#addItems {
  width: 70px;
}

.productProject button:active {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #795548, #A1887F);
  border: 2px solid #795548;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #2D2020;
}

.productProject button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.productProject input {
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #8D6E63;
}

.productProject input::placeholder {
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  color: lightgray;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.productProject input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.productProject input[type='number'] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

.productProject input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.productProject input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.productProject__productList__list {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.productProject__productList__list--product {
  width: 100px;
}

.productProject__productList__list caption {
  background: #4E342E;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  color: white;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.productProject__productList__list td,
.productProject__productList__list th {
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.productProject__productList__list th {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.productProject__productList__list tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #EFEBE9;
}

.productProject__productList__list table {
  border: 1px solid #b8b6b6;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-spacing: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.productProject__productList__list th {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #896d6d94;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #2D2020;
}

.productProject__productList__list tr td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.productProject__productList {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.productProject__productList__list tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.productProject__productList__list thead {
  background-color: #8D6E63;
}

.productProject__productList__list thead tr {
  display: block;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.productProject__productList__list th,
.productProject__productList__list td {
  width: 125px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="productProject" id="productList" v-cloak>
  <div>
    <div class="productProject__forms">
      <span>Товар</span>
      <div>
        <input type="text" v-model.trim="productName" placeholder="Наименование товара" v-on:blur="blurCondition()">
        <div v-if="isTouched && productName.length == 0" class="productProject__forms__errorMessage">Поле пустое! Введите наименование товара.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="productProject__forms">
      <span>Количество</span>
      <div>
        <input type="number" v-model.number="quantity" v-on:blur="blurCondition()" placeholder="Количество продуктов">
        <div v-if="isTouched && quantity <= 0" class="productProject__forms__errorMessage">Поле не может содержать пустое и значение, равное "0".</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="productProject__forms">
      <span>Стоимость</span>
      <div>
        <input type="number" v-model.number="cost" placeholder="Цена товара">
        <div v-if="isTouched && cost == 0 || cost.length == 0" class="productProject__forms__errorMessage">Поле не может содержать пустое и значение, равное 0.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <button v-on:click="choiceAction()" v-bind:disabled="inputValidation">{{ currentItemIndex == null ? 'Добавить' : 'Сохранить' }}</button>
  </div>
  <div class="productProject__productList">
    <table class="productProject__productList__list">
      <caption>Список продуктов</caption>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Товар</th>
          <th>Количество</th>
          <th>Стоимость</th>
          <th>Сумма</th>
          <th>Действие</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="(newElement, index) in products" id="project">
          <td>{{ newElement.product }}</td>
          <td>{{ newElement.quantity }}</td>
          <td>{{ newElement.cost }}</td>
          <td>{{ newElement.quantity * newElement.cost }}</td>
          <td>
            <div class="productProject__productList__icons">
              <div v-on:click="edit(index)" class="productProject__productList__icons__editIcon">
              </div>
              <div v-on:click="deleteItem(index)" class="productProject__productList__icons__deleteIcon"></div>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: исправила, спасибо! какие еще замечания?

Comment: работает все в случае, где верстка НЕ компонентная. С компонентной проблемы. Консоль при вводе данных в форму выдает ошибки: " Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "productName" " 
Кнопка "Добавить" также не работает. При клике ошибки: 1)Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" и 2) Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: у меня потому вопросы по моему переносу обычной стандартной верстки с программой в компонентную. На желтом фоне в вопросе я прикрепила ссылки на мои проблемные компоненты

Comment: если вам не сложно! буду ждать! касаемо props. В видеоуроке по Вью была предложена такая идея связки компонентов, потому и пытаюсь использовать это. Спасибо еще разок, жду

Comment: @РустамГимранов прочитала в интернете, что `props` vue рассматривает как анти-шаблон. Читала на всевозможных форумах, где люди столкнулись с аналогичной моей проблемой. Но так и не поняла, что значит антишаблон..Вы не сориентируете? И если использование `props` такое проблемное, что лучше использовать на его замену? В документации очень четко все изложено касаемо `props` тоже, теперь я в сомнениях вообще

Comment: @РустамГимранов добавила

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined"

Вы пытаетесь добавить в массив элемент, но данный элемент не определен в контексте компонента. В компоненте `form.vue` не определена модель `products`. А вы пытаетесь туда что-то "спушить" (добавить).

> Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value.

Избегайте прямого изменения свойства (props), так как значение будет перезаписываться при каждом повторном рендеринге родительского компонента. Вместо этого используйте `data` или `computed` (вычисляемое свойство), основанное на значении свойства (props).

---

В примере ниже показаны два способа передачи свойств в дочерние компоненты. В этом [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/975549/256824) есть описания других методов взаимодействия компонентов.

```js
// Отключим ненужные для примера сообщения в консоли.
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

const ProductForm = {
  template: `
<form ref="form" @submit.prevent="onSubmit" @input="resetAllErrors">
    <div class="productProject__forms">
        <span>Товар</span>
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Наименование товара" v-model.trim="product.name" />
            <div v-for="error in errors.name" class="productProject__forms__errorMessage">{{ error }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="productProject__forms">
        <span>Количество</span>
        <div>
            <input type="number" placeholder="Количество продуктов" v-model.number="product.quantity" />
            <div v-for="error in errors.quantity" class="productProject__forms__errorMessage">{{ error }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="productProject__forms">
        <span>Стоимость</span>
        <div>
            <input type="number" placeholder="Цена товара" v-model.number="product.cost" />
            <div v-for="error in errors.cost" class="productProject__forms__errorMessage">{{ error }}</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit">{{ labelButton }}</button>
    <pre>{{ value }}</pre>
</form>`,
  name: 'product-form',
  props: {
    // Данное свойство было передано
    // компоненту ч/з `v-model`.
    value: Object
  },
  data() {
    return {
      // Модель с ошибками валидации.
      errors: {}
    }
  },
  computed: {
    // Мы не меняем переданные свойства `props`,
    // а задаем локальные переменные для работы с ними.
    // В разделе `computed`, чтобы отследить изменения
    // в родительском компоненте [в данном случае].
    product() {
      return {
        ...this.value
      }
    },
    labelButton() {
      return !this.product.id ? 'Добавить' : 'Сохранить'
    },
    hasErrors() {
      return !!Object.keys(this.errors).length
    }
  },
  watch: {
    // Коллбэк будет вызываться каждый раз,
    // когда изменяется любое из свойств наблюдаемого объекта
    // https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch
    'product.id': {
      // При изменении `id`, сбрасываем все ошибки.
      handler: 'resetAllErrors'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      // При успешной валидации формы,
      if (this.validate()) {
        // пробрасываем событие с аргументами
        // в родительский компонент.
        this.$emit('input', this.product)
      }
    },
    validate() {
      // Сбросим все ошибки.
      this.resetAllErrors()

      this.validateName()
      this.validateQuantity()
      this.validateСost()

      // Возвращаем значение вычисляемого поля.
      return !this.hasErrors
    },
    validateName() {
      // Сбросим ошибки о наименовании.
      this.errors.name = []
      // Проверим длину наименования товара.
      if (!this.product.name.length) {
        this.errors.name.push('Наименование товара обязательно к заполнению.')
      }
      // Если нет ошибок в поле, принудительно удаляем информацию.
      if (!this.errors.name.length) {
        this.resetError('name')
      }
    },
    validateQuantity() {
      this.errors.quantity = []
      if (this.product.quantity <= 0) {
        this.errors.quantity.push('Поле должно быть больше 0.')
      }
      if (!this.errors.quantity.length) {
        this.resetError('quantity')
      }
    },
    validateСost() {
      this.errors.cost = []
      if (this.product.cost <= 0) {
        this.errors.cost.push('Поле должно быть больше 0.')
      }
      if (!this.errors.cost.length) {
        this.resetError('cost')
      }
    },
    resetError(field) {
      delete this.errors[field]
    },
    resetAllErrors() {
      this.errors = {}
    }
  }
}

const ProductList = {
  template: `
<div class="productProject__productList">
    <table class="productProject__productList__list">
        <caption>Список продуктов</caption>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>#</th><th>Товар</th><th>Количество</th><th>Стоимость</th><th>Сумма</th><th>Действие</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="(product, index) in filteredProducts" :key="product.id">
                <td>{{ product.id }}</td>
                <td>{{ product.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ product.quantity }}</td>
                <td>{{ product.cost }}</td>
                <td>{{ product.quantity * product.cost }}</td>
                <td>
                    <div class="productProject__productList__icons">
                        <div @click="edit(product.id)" class="productProject__productList__icons__editIcon"></div>
                        <div @click="remove(product.id)" class="productProject__productList__icons__deleteIcon"></div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>`,
  name: 'product-list',
  props: {
    products: Array
  },
  computed: {
    // Опять же, мы не меняем переданные свойства `props`,
    // а задаем локальные переменные для работы с ними.
    // В разделе `computed`, т.к. обычно к спискам применяют
    // различные методы фильтрации.
    filteredProducts() {
      return this.$props.products
    }
  },
  methods: {
    edit(id) {
      // Пробрасываем событие с аргументами в родительский компонент.
      this.$emit('edit', id)
    },
    remove(id) {
      // Пробрасываем событие с аргументами в родительский компонент.
      this.$emit('remove', id)
    }
  }
}

const App = {
  template: `
<div class="productProject">
    <!-- Передаём свойства ч/з 'v-model' -->
    <product-form v-model="product" @input="save"></product-form>

    <!-- Передаём свойства ч/з директиву 'v-bind' -->
    <product-list :products="products" @edit="edit" @remove="remove"></product-list>
</div>`,
  components: {
    'product-form': ProductForm,
    'product-list': ProductList
  },
  data() {
    return {
      // Модель текущего товара.
      product: {
        id: null,
        name: '',
        quantity: 1,
        cost: 1
      },
      // Модель всех товаров.
      products: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Хлеб',
        quantity: 4,
        cost: 30
      }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Яблоко',
        quantity: 8,
        cost: 18
      }],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    save(product) {
      // Если в переданном продукте есть `id`,
      // отличное от изначального `null`.
      !product.id ? this.create(product) : this.update(product)

      // Сбрасываем текущие значения.
      this.product = {
        id: null,
        name: '',
        quantity: 1,
        cost: 1
      }
    },

    /**
     * Добавление нового продукта.
     */
    create(product) {
      // Вот такая хитрая схема по поиску
      // последнего элемента в списке.
      let last = this.products[this.products.length - 1]

      // Увеличиваем `id` на единицу.
      product.id = last ? last.id + 1 : 1

      // Добавляем в конец массива `products`.
      this.products.push(product)
    },

    /**
     * Передаём данные в форму редактирования.
     */
    edit(id) {
      this.product = this.products.find(item => item.id === id)
    },

    /**
     * Обновление существующего продукта.
     */
    update(product) {
      let index = this.products.findIndex(item => item.id === product.id)

      this.products.splice(index, 1, product)
    },

    /**
     * Удаление существующего продукта по `id`.
     */
    remove(id) {
      let index = this.products.findIndex(item => item.id === id)

      this.products.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    App
  },
  template: `<app></app>`
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgb(255, 246, 246);
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #eaeafe8c, #e3e3e3);
}

.productProject {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

[v-cloak] {
  display: none;
}

.productProject__forms {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.productProject__forms__errorMessage {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #ff0000;
  width: 190px;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.productProject__forms__buttons {
  display: flex;
}

.productProject__forms span {
  display: block;
  width: 90px;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.productProject__productList--btnStyle {
  width: 124px;
}

.productProject__productList__icons {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.productProject__productList__icons__deleteIcon {
  background: url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/61/61848.png) no-repeat;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-size: contain;
  opacity: .2;
}

.productProject__productList__icons__deleteIcon:hover,
.productProject__productList__icons__editIcon:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.productProject__productList__icons__editIcon {
  background: url(https://img2.freepng.ru/20180616/fiu/kisspng-computer-icons-drawing-pencil-pencil-icon-5b256b0984a045.2039086015291788895433.jpg) no-repeat;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-size: contain;
  opacity: .2;
}

.productProject button {
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #A1887F, #795548);
  border: 2px solid #795548;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #2D2020;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.productProject button:disabled {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #c1c1c2, #6e6e6e);
  border: 2px solid #979797;
}

.productProject button#addItems {
  width: 70px;
}

.productProject button:active {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #795548, #A1887F);
  border: 2px solid #795548;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #2D2020;
}

.productProject button:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.productProject input {
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  background-color: #8D6E63;
}

.productProject input::placeholder {
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  color: lightgray;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.productProject input:focus {
  outline: 0;
}

.productProject input[type='number'] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}

.productProject input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
.productProject input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.productProject__productList__list {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.productProject__productList__list--product {
  width: 100px;
}

.productProject__productList__list caption {
  background: #4E342E;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  color: white;
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 26px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.productProject__productList__list td,
.productProject__productList__list th {
  font-family: "Roboto Slab", serif;
  word-break: break-all;
}

.productProject__productList__list th {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.productProject__productList__list tr:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #EFEBE9;
}

.productProject__productList__list table {
  border: 1px solid #b8b6b6;
  font-size: 14px;
  border-spacing: 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.productProject__productList__list th {
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #896d6d94;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #2D2020;
}

.productProject__productList__list tr td:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.productProject__productList {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.productProject__productList__list tbody {
  display: block;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.productProject__productList__list thead {
  background-color: #8D6E63;
}

.productProject__productList__list thead tr {
  display: block;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.productProject__productList__list th,
.productProject__productList__list td {
  width: 125px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak></div>

<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10'></script>
```

В любом случае: в дочерние компоненты вы передаёте свойства, а из дочерних в родительский вызываете события ($emit) по изменению этих свойств.