# Добавление одного и того же компонента на страницу через кнопку

Tags: vue.js

Необходимо при нажатии на кнопку добавить компонент, однако добавляется лишь название компонента. Как исправить?

```js
Vue.component('component-a', {
 template: '<h3>Hello world!</h3>'
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   arr: []
    },
    methods: {
     add(){
       this.arr.push('component-a');
        console.dir(this.arr)
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <component-a></component-a>
  
  <hr>
  <button @click="add">Add a component</button>
  <ul>
  <li v-for="component in arr"> {{ component }} </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Наводящий вопрос: какой смысл от абсолютно одинаковых компонентов с одинаковым содержимым?

Comment: Ну начинается... Я вот дивлюсь от людей здесь. Вроде везде тех.специалисты, а столько много слов пишут вместо кода. Больше, чем на форумах по философии. Ну ладно, отвечу: я делаю приложение, где создаются карточки клиентов с энным кол-вом заказов, которые могут редактироваться, удаляться или добавляться. Соответственно, под каждого клиента я создаю разные заказы с разными подзаказами. Одним словом, кнопка с добавлением одинаковых компонентов на странице необходима. 
Так поможете кодом, как это сделать? Я полдня маюсь уже, не получается.

Comment: Хотите код https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/984023/256824 демка рабочая

Comment: Вам нужно не компоненты добавлять, а сущностями в массиве манипулировать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю отказаться от Вашего решения, добавления компонента в переменную. Так не делается, нужно манипулировать данными и создавать компоненты на основе имеющейся информации. Получите данные о клиенте и его заказе! и при использовании `for` подставляйте в качестве `props` эти данные. Тем самым Вы создаёте "одинаковый" компонент, но с уникальными данными. К примеру, мы получили пользователя и его заказ (допустим заказов у клиента не было и `arr` у нас пустой поэтому). Далее при нажатии на кнопку `add` мы добавим шаблон заказа в массив `arr`, для передачи его `component-a` то есть компоненту отображения заказа! (формы инпуты и прочее) Пример(200vh в css так как vue консоль выводит. и снипет не показывает вывод нормально):

```js
Vue.component('component-a', {
  props: ['item'],
 template: '<h3>{{item.title}} {{item.idOrder}}</h3>'
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
   arr: []
    },
    methods: {
     add(){
       this.arr.push({
         idOrder: Math.random().toFixed(2),
         title: 'Номер заказа:'
        });
        
      }
    }
})
```

```css
#app {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h3>Hello</h3>
  <hr>
  <button @click="add">Add a component</button>
  <ul>
  <li v-for="component in arr"> 
    <component-a :item="component"></component-a> 
  </li>
</ul>
</div>
```