# Vue.js - Как вернуть данные в родительский компонент?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

У меня есть родительский компонент куда в data() я хочу передать вычисляемое свойство из дочерного компонента.

```
// ParentComponent.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <ChildComponent :parent="parent"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from '@/components/ChildComponent';

export default {
  name: 'ParentComponent',
  components: {
    ChildComponent,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      parent: {
        parentData: '',
      }
    };
  },
</script>
```

В дочернем компоненте вычисляемое свойство это конкатенация строк, полей свойства data дочерного компонента.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="control">
      <input
        v-model="salarySumm"
        class="input"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Add the estimated salary (1000 - 2000)"
      >
      <div class="select">
        <select v-model="salaryCode">
          <option disabled value>Select currency</option>
          <option
            v-for="(el, index) in currency"
            :key="index"
            :value="el.code"
          >{{ el.title }}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>  
export default {
  name: 'ChildComponent',
  props: ['parent'],
  data() {
    return {
      salarySumm: '',
      salaryCode: '',
    }
  },
  created() {
    // Тут я получаю массив объектов в виде 
    // [{ title: 'string', code: 'string' }]
    this.$store.dispatch('getCurrencies')
  },
  computed: {
    currency() {
      let list = this.$store.getters.currencies.data
      const currencyList = []
      if (list !== undefined) {
        for (const el of list) {
          if (el.code == '(none)' || el.code == null) el.code = ''
          if (el.name !== null) {
            currencyList.push({ title: `${el.name} | ${el.code}`, code: el.code })
          }
        }
      }
      return currencyList
    },
    salary() {
      // Здесь я получаю строку в том виде, в котором хочу передать ее в родительский компонент.
      return this.salarySumm + ' ' + this.salaryCode
    },
</script>
```

Как мне передать вычисляемое свойство salary в родительский компонент, а точнее в parent.parentData?

Comment: `$emit(); `https://medium.com/@modex13/vue-js-2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-467383294847

Comment: Во всех примерах что я находил $emit слушает события, у меня нет событий.

Comment: `$emit` не слушает, а пробрасывает родителю, вызывая родительский метод.

Comment: У родителя форма где есть свои поля и поля-компоненты, это одно из них. При заполнении всех будет submit и отправка в базу.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В дочерние компоненты вы передаёте свойства, а из дочерних в родительский вызываете события `$emit` по изменению свойств:

```
// Родительский компонент.
<template>
  <child-component :someProps="parent" @updateParent="onUpdateSalary" />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    // Локальные данные компонента.
    data() {
      return {
        parent: {
          parentData: '',
        }
      }
    },

    methods: {
      onUpdateSalary(someData) {
        // Выполняем необходимые действия с `someData`
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

```
// Дочерний компонент.
<template>
  <button type="button" @click="doSomething">Передать родителю</button>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    // Входящие свойства из родителя.
    props: ['someProps'],

    // Локальные данные компонента.
    data() {
      return {
        amount: '',
        code: '',
      }
    },

    methods: {
      doSomething() {
        this.$emit('updateParent', {
          amount: this.amount,
          code: this.code
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

---

Если нужно передать вычисляемое свойство `computed` родительскому компоненту, то необходимо использовать наблюдатель `watch`, которому задаётся функция обработчик вызываемая при каждом изменении вычисляемого (и не только) свойства. Пример ниже.

```js
// Отключим ненужные для примера
// сообщения в консоли.
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

Vue.component('parent-component', {
  template: `
        <div>
            <child-component :someProps="parent" @updateParent="onUpdateSalary" />
            <p v-if="parentSalary">
                Значение <b>parentSalary</b>, отображаемое в "parent-component": <pre>{{ parentSalary }}</pre>
            </p>
        </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      // Родительское значение.
      parentSalary: null,
      parent: {
        parentData: '... из поля data',
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onUpdateSalary(data) {
      this.parentSalary = data
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('child-component', {
  template: `
        <div>
            <pre>Свойство из родительского компонента: {{ someProps.parentData }}</pre>
            <div v-if="currencies.length" class="control">
                <input type="number" v-model.number="amount" class="input" />
                <select v-model="code">
                    <option disabled selected>Select currency</option>
                    <template v-for="(currency, index) in currencies">
                        <option :key="index" :value="currency.code">{{ currency.name }}</option>
                    </template>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div v-else>Нет данных для отображения.</div>
            <p v-if="salary">Значение <b>salary</b>, отображаемое в "child-component": <b>{{ salary }}</b></p>
        </div>`,
  props: ['someProps'],
  data() {
    return {
      amount: '',
      code: '',

      currencies: [{
          "code": "EUR",
          "name": "Euro"
        },
        {
          "code": "GBP",
          "name": "U.K. Pound Sterling"
        },
        {
          "code": "JPY",
          "name": "Japanese Yen"
        }
      ]
    }
  },

  computed: {
    salary() {
      return this.amount + ' ' + this.code
    }
  },

  watch: {
    // Эта функция запускается при любом изменении значений
    // в вычисляемом свойстве `salary`.
    salary(newValue, oldValue) {
      // Пробрасываем данные родительскому компоненту,
      // ч/з вызов метода.
      this.$emit('updateParent', {
        amount: this.amount,
        code: this.code
      })
    }
  }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {}
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <parent-component></parent-component>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10"></script>
```

```
  computed: {
    salary() {
      return this.amount + ' ' + this.code
    }
  },

  watch: {
    // Эта функция запускается при любом изменении значений
    // в вычисляемом свойстве `salary`.
    salary(newValue, oldValue) {
      // Пробрасываем данные родительскому компоненту,
      // ч/з вызов метода.
      this.$emit('updateParent', {
        amount: this.amount,
        code: this.code
      })
    }
  }
```

---

Судя по коду `this.$store.dispatch` вы используете `vuex`. В таком случае, можно всю логику перенести в хранилище. Это освободит от постоянных проверок полученных данных в каждом компоненте.

```js
// Отключим ненужные для примера
// сообщения в консоли.
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

// Список доступных мутаций (сеттеры).
const CASH_INIT = 'CASH_INIT'
const CASH_SET_AMOUNT = 'CASH_SET_AMOUNT'
const CASH_SET_CODE = 'CASH_SET_CODE'

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    amount: null,
    code: null,
    currencies: []
  },

  getters: {
    amount: state => state.amount,
    code: state => state.code,
    currencies: state => state.currencies,
    salary: state => {
      if (state.amount && state.code) {
        return state.amount + ' ' + state.code
      }

      return null
    }
  },

  // Обработчики мутаций обязаны быть синхронными.
  mutations: {
    [CASH_INIT](state, currencies) {
      state.currencies = currencies
    },
    [CASH_SET_AMOUNT](state, amount) {
      amount = parseFloat(amount)

      if (!isNaN(amount)) {
        state.amount = amount
      } else {
        state.amount = ''
        alert('Ошибка в типе данных: `amount`.')
      }
    },
    [CASH_SET_CODE](state, code) {
      code = code.toString()

      if (code) {
        state.code = code
      } else {
        state.code = ''
        alert('Ошибка в типе данных: `code`.')
      }
    }
  },

  actions: {
    getCurrencies(context) {
      try {
        // В своем проекте используйте `fetch` или axios, например.
        // const response = await fetch('http://www.floatrates.com/daily/usd.json')
        // const data = await response.json()
        // context.commit('CASH_INIT', data)

        context.commit('CASH_INIT', [{
          "code": "EUR",
          "name": "Euro"
        }, {
          "code": "GBP",
          "name": "U.K. Pound Sterling"
        }, {
          "code": "JPY",
          "name": "Japanese Yen"
        }, {
          "code": "AUD",
          "name": "Australian Dollar"
        }, {
          "code": "CAD",
          "name": "Canadian Dollar"
        }, {
          "code": "CHF",
          "name": "Swiss Franc"
        }, {
          "code": "UYU",
          "name": "Uruguayan Peso"
        }])
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      }
    },

    calculate(context, {
      amount,
      code
    }) {
      context.commit('CASH_SET_AMOUNT', amount)
      context.commit('CASH_SET_CODE', code)
    },
  }
})

Vue.component('child-component', {
  template: `
<div>
  <div v-if="currencies.length" class="control">
    <input type="number" v-model.number="amount" class="input" />
    <select v-model="code">
      <option disabled selected>Select currency</option>
      <template v-for="(currency, index) in currencies">
      <option :key="index" :value="currency.code">{{ currency.name }}</option>
      </template>
    </select>
    <button type="button" @click="send">Отправить данные во vuex</button>
  </div>
  <div v-else>Нет данных для отображения.</div>
</div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      amount: '',
      code: '',
    }
  },

  computed: {
    // При компонентном подходе ...mapGetters()
    ...Vuex.mapGetters(['currencies']),
  },

  mounted() {
    this.getCurrencies()
  },

  methods: {
    // При компонентном подходе ...mapActions().
    // Теперь в компоненте доступны методы:
    // this.getCurrencies() и this.calculate(...)
    ...Vuex.mapActions(['getCurrencies', 'calculate']),

    send() {
      this.calculate({
        amount: this.amount,
        code: this.code
      })
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('parent-component', {
  template: `
<div>
  <child-component />
  <p v-if="salary">Значение <b>salary</b>, отображаемое в "parent-component": <b>{{ salary }}</b></p>
</div>`,
  data() {
    return {}
  },

  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapGetters([
      'salary',
    ]),
  },
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  data: {},

  // Используя vuex получаем доступ к хранилище
  // не только в дочерних и родительских компонентах.
  computed: {
    ...Vuex.mapGetters([
      'salary',
    ]),
  },
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div>
    <p v-if="salary">Значение <b>salary</b> в корне приложения: <b>{{ salary }}</b></p>
    <parent-component></parent-component>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@2.0.0"></script>
```

Посмотрите другие примеры в этих ответах [984023](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/984023/256824), [975447](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/975549/256824).

Answer (score 1):

Немного разобравшись с темой хочу дать и свой ответ.

**Первый вариант:**
Но этот вариант имеет один недостаток, если не отображать результат вычисляемого свойства в компоненте, то мы не будем "дергать" его и оно не будет вычисляться. Т.е. этот метод годится только если вы хотите в этом же методе и использовать вычисляемое свойство например так

```
<div>Salary: {{ salary }}</div>
```

Я покажу как можно прокинуть данные в родителя с помощью $emit но без якобы использования события.
Все дело в том, что $emit и есть наше собственное событие. Вот полезная статья про [Пользовательские события](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-v-model-%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0).

В дочернем компоненте, я использую computed потому что он всегда пересчитывает данные которые меняются и сам факт пересчета и есть в неком смысле событие. Computed  кроме возврата значения может создает некие побочные эффекты, запись данных куда то в данном случает в событие input (см. computed ниже). Останется только прописать пропс в дочернем компоненте и именем value.

```
// ChildComponent.vue
<script>  
export default {
  name: 'ChildComponent',
  props: ['value'],
  data() {
    return {
      salarySumm: '',
      salaryCode: '',
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getCurrencies')
  },
  computed: {
    currency() {
      let list = this.$store.getters.currencies.data
      const currencyList = []
      if (list !== undefined) {
        for (const el of list) {
          if (el.code == '(none)' || el.code == null) el.code = ''
          if (el.name !== null) {
            currencyList.push({ title: `${el.name} | ${el.code}`, code: el.code })
          }
        }
      }
      return currencyList
    },
    salary() {
      let salary = this.salarySumm + ' ' + this.salaryCode
      this.$emit('input', salary)
      return salary
    },
</script>
```

и далее в родителе получить эти данные через v-model

```
// ParentComponent.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <ChildComponent v-model="parent.parentData"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ChildComponent from '@/components/ChildComponent';

export default {
  name: 'ParentComponent',
  components: {
    ChildComponent,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      parent: {
        parentData: '',
      }
    };
  },
</script>
```

**Второй вариант.**
Я использую внутренние события для того что бы вызвать метод который создать пользовательское событие $emit

```
// ParentComponent.vue
// Все то же самое что и в варианте 1

// ChildComponent.vue
// В шаблоне я явно привязываю событие к моему методу который склеит строки и создаст пользовательское событие. Этот метод в варианте 1 был вычисляемым свойством.
div class="control">
  <input
    v-model="salarySumm"
    class="input"
    type="text"
    placeholder="Add the estimated salary (1000 - 2000)"
    v-on:input="salary"
  >
  <div class="select">
    <select v-model="salaryCode" @change="salary()">
      <option disabled value>Select currency</option>
      <option
        v-for="(el, index) in currency"
        :key="index"
        :value="el.code"
      >{{ el.title }}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

// Вместо вычисляемого свойства computed я создаю метод
methods: {
  salary() {
    this.$emit('input', this.salarySumm + ' ' + this.salaryCode)
  },
}
```