# Не отслеживает изменения в watch

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Так я передаю объект с данными в родительском контроле,который находится в `popup` окне:

```
<k-control :data="data" :list_analyses="list.find(el=> el.AnalysisName == 'Гемоглобин')"/>
```

В дочернем контроле он приходит в `props: ['list_analyses']`. Я его раскладываю в `input` с проверками `:value="list_analyses ? list_analyses.UnitName : ''"`.

Проблема в отслеживании изменений этого объекта, который приходит в дочерний компонент. Есть `watch`, который должен следить за изменениями:

```
watch: {
  list_analyses: {
            handler: function (newVal, oldVal){
                console.log('newVal = ',newVal, 'oldVal = ', oldVal)
            },
            deep: true
        }
}
```

А он срабатывает только в момент, когда открываю `popup` окно, но не в момент редактирования данных.

Comment: Добавь `console.log()` и посмотри срабатывает он или нет.

Comment: @doox911 ну вроде там и есть консоль в функции, срабатывает только в момент вызова popup и все, не в момент редактирования данных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по вопросу, основная проблема - передача и синхронизация данных между дочерним и родительским компонентами. Схожие [ответы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/985344/256824).

```js
// Отключим ненужные для примера
// сообщения в консоли.
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.config.devtools = false

const KControl = {
  props: ['list', 'analysis_name'],
  data() {
    return {
      analysis: {}
    }
  },
  // При создании компонента отыскиваем необходимый элемент.
  created() {
    this.analysis = this.$props.list.find(el => el.AnalysisName == this.$props.analysis_name)
  },
  template: `<div>
                <label>{{ analysis_name }}</label>
                <input type="text" v-model="analysis.UnitName" />
            </div>`,
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'k-control': KControl
  },
  data: {
    list_analyses: [
      {AnalysisName: 'Гемоглобин', UnitName: 4.8},
      {AnalysisName: 'Aльбумин', UnitName: 43.4}
    ]
  }
});
```

```css
label {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <template v-for="item in list_analyses">
            <!--
                Передаём в дочерний компонент весь список и идентификатор,
                по которому будет осуществлен поиск необходимо элемента из списка.
            -->
            <k-control :list="list_analyses" :analysis_name="item.AnalysisName"></k-control>
        </template>
  <h3>Данные в родительском компоненте:</h3>
  <pre>{{ list_analyses }}</pre>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10"></script>
```

---